# Ruby assignment inside an iterator

Tags: ruby

I want to convert the name "JOHN DOE-SMITH" to "John Doe-Smith" using the code:

```
name = "JOHN DOE-SMITH"  
name_split = name.split(/\s/)  
name_split.each do |x|  
  if x =~ /-/  
    name1, name2 = x.split(/-/)  
    x = name1.capitalize + "-" + name2.capitalize  
  else  
    x.capitalize!  
  end  
end  
puts name_split.join(" ")
```

The result is the unexpected "John DOE-SMITH"
Why does x.capitalize! have an effect while x = "foo" has none?
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
cap_name = name.split.map{|w| w.split("-").map(&:capitalize).join("-") }.join(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

`x = "foo"` just assigns the variable `x` to reference a different object. Since that variable only exists in the block, this has no observable effect. It doesn't change the string at all. `x.capitalize!`, on the other hand, sends the `capitalize!` message to the string, which causes it to change case.

Answer (score 0):

Because x is a local variable that points to a string using the same data. This is why affecting a new value to it doesn't change inside the string.

You might want to rethink a little your strategy here ; it is dependant on the fact that the split string refers to the same memory area as the original string, which I wouldn't bet holds true in all cases.
I'd suggest to use .map instead:

```
name_split = name.split(/\s/).map do |x|
  if x =~ /-/
    name1, name2 = x.split(/-/)
    name1.capitalize + "-" + name2.capitalize
  else
    x.capitalize
  end
end  
puts name_split.join(" ")
```

Or if you find this more readable:

```
name_split = name.split(/\s/).map do |x|
  x.split(/-/).map(&:capitalize).join('-')
end
puts name_split.join(" ")
```